# Как на практике применяются size_t и обобщенные указатели (void *)?

Tags: c, libc

Переписываю часть стандартной библиотеки C для лучшего ее понимания. Наткнулся на `size_t` и `void *` в прототипах функций, например, `memset`. Я понял как работают обобщенные указатели и то, что `size_t` - это `typedef unsigned int`, но не могу найти конкретные примеры того, зачем используются `size_t` и `void *`. Понял, что для портируемости, но как это применяется на практике?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

size_t - это тип, возвращаемый операцией sizeof. Соответственно, он используется там, где ожидается размер данных. Размер переменной size_t - 4 байта для 32-битной программы, и 8 байт для 64-битной. По большому счету использовать его необязательно, и если вы вместо size_t будете использовать подходящее целое, то ничего не потеряете.

void* имеет более существенное практическое применение. Он совместим с любым указателем, поэтому очень удобно его использовать там, где тип указателя неизвестен. Например, если мы пишем функцию записи в файл, то void* позволяет вызывать ее с любым указателем без приведения типа:

```
void WriteBuffer(const void * buf, size_t len) {
. . .
}

. . .

int j;
char str[80];
struct {
  POINT x;
  POINT y;
} coord;

. . .

WriteBuffer(&j, sizeof(j));
WriteBuffer(str, sizeof(str));
WriteBuffer(&coord, sizeof(coord));
```

А если бы мы объявили аргумент как указатель на массив байт:

```
void WriteBuffer(LPCBYTE buf, size_t len) {
```

то нам пришлось бы делать каст при каждом вызове (разве что кроме массива char):

```
WriteBuffer((LPCBYTE)&j, sizeof(j));
WriteBuffer((LPCBYTE)&coord, sizeof(coord));
```

Comment: Указатель на функцию нельзя кастовать к `void*`.